# Does the noun "stable" have meanings other than "place for animals"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I came across someone noting that an English term for the [training area of Sumo wrestlers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heya_%28sumo%29) is "sumo stable", and that "stable" is usually a word used for horses. She found it a bit funny. I'm not sure whether she meant "funny" as in "haha", or "funny" as in "strange".

Wiktionary doesn't have any definitions of [stable](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stable#Noun) other than a place for animals, or the horses from a stable.

Do English-speakers view sumo wrestlers as being like animals, or is there a meaning of "stable" that I'm unaware of?

Comment: This has nothing to do with sumo wrestlers; _stable_ can be applied to writers, producers, editors, companions Hungarian enterprises, computers, consultants, investment banks, exercise gurus – oh, yes, and horses, too. [Have a look](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22has%20a%20stable%20of%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1980,cd_max:2005&lr=lang_en).

Comment: It's metaphorical, you dog.

Comment: Should this question have been asked on English Language Learners instead?

Comment: @Kris: It looks like the first part of my comment may be in error then, but I stand by the second: that _stable_ can be used to describe a group of about anything, including people – not just horses and sumo wrestlers.

Comment: @J.R. I thought your whole comment was on target. How do you think it was wrong? It doesn't contradict that 'stable' is used often for sumo.

Comment: @Mitch, I agree there is no contradiction, but the link posted by Kris leads me to believe that _stable_ is no arbitary word, and that those who know the sport would be unlikely to substitute a word like _pool_ or _coalition_ in that context.

Comment: @J.R.: Right, it's not arbitrary, but even though it is a 'set phrase', it's still metaphorical. The OP wonders if English speakers think sumo wrestlers are like animals, and that is an extreme literal view that is not borne out by usage.

Comment: It's important to note that the original Japanese term 'heya' or 'beya' more likely corresponds to 'room' and that it is an English metaphor to use the word 'stable', especially since which ever term is used, the concept it refers to is about a number of things: the group of wrestlers, the place of training, and the organization itself, all together. Like 'gym', or the related Japanese 'dojo', but with an emphasis on the individuals in it themselves.

Comment: You seem to have confused Wiktionary for the OED.

Comment: @tchrist snarky!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently,

1. The Japanese word (transliterated) heya has been drafted into the English language now:

> **heya** (sumo) the so-called "stable" of rikishi who train under the instruction of a particular shisho; the place where this group lives
>   and trains

[Wiktionary]

This word, like quite a few in English, has concrete and (at-least-almost-totally) abstract usages, usually for associated organisations:

> The school was built in 1963. / It's one of England's top schools.
>
> My club is just round the corner. / I do not wish to be a member of
>   any club that will accept *me* as a member.
>
> The kennel collapsed. / We left Rex at the kennels for a week.
>
> This is Red Rum's stable. / I recommend Piggott's Stables for your
>   racehorses.

There is often a further metaphorical distancing possible:

> Claude Monet is recognised as the leader of the Impressionist School.
>
> [The] epoch-making Avro Canada Jetliner from the same stable as the
>   CF-100 and the Arrow ...

It is not clear to me whether 'sumo stable' is generally held to cover the largely concrete sense of 'training area / facilities for sumo wrestlers' in addition to the obviously acceptable abstract sense seemingly corresponding to 'boxing club'.

At http://web-japan.org/kidsweb//virtual/sumo/sumo04.html is evidence suggesting that the more concrete sense *is* used:

> Wrestlers wake up early in the morning and train hard in the hope of
>   moving up the ranks. Mornings in a sumo stable begin at around 5:00
>   am. First, the unranked wrestlers begin their training. Each stable
>   has a ring for practice.

(I would expect different phrasings if these usages of *stable* were intended to reference the wrestlers - eg *Mornings **for** a sumo stable begin*... .)

Answer (score 4):

From **not** the OED proper, which is paywalled, but rather [the free Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stable--2):

> an organization or establishment training or producing a particular
>   type of person or product: the player comes from the same stable as
>   Agassi